# AD&D 2e Creature immunities

Tags: monsters, adnd-2e, immunities

So, unless I'm missing something, **AD&D 2nd** edition is not very informative about *creature immunities*... As a result, such things are up to individual Dungeon Master interpretations and campaign settings.

So my question is: what would a DM do? That is to say, which are the creature types (i.e. Undead, Constructs, Elementals, Salamanders, Trolls, Dragons and the like) generally immune to Charm / Hold / Paralysis / Confusion / Petrification / Polymorph / Stun / Confusion / Berserk / Feeblemind / Disease / Poison ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In AD&D 2e, there were no "creature types" as used in the 5e sense, ie. tags that helped to identify how certain effects interacted with certain creatures. (You can polymorph to beasts, conjure celestials, protection from good and evil shields against certain types, etc.) There were also no types à la 3e, which provided a set of
common properties that different creatures shared.

The defenses of each creature would be written in the "Special defenses" entry under its monster manual/compendium page. Further information could also be found in the "Combat" section. And occasionally, for certain creatures like dragons, beholderkin, tanarri, etc, there would be monster manual/compendium pages which went like "Aasimon, General Information" and some common properties would be defined for a couple of creatures.

I personally encountered such general info pages mostly in the Planescape products, as each plane had different rules of physics and magic and specific denizens that seemed to match with the plane. Baatezu for Baator, tanar'ri for the Abyss, slaadi for Limbo, eladrin for Arborea, etc. You can look for their "General Information" pages. (All these would be outsiders in 3e and fiends/celestials in 5e.)

So I am afraid there is no general official answer to your question.

Comment: Good answer.  Could be improved by citing an example or two of a creature 'type' OP references, and/or thing OP lists that something might be immune to to both provide text support for your assertion and demonstrate the language used in 2e.

Comment: In 5e there are creature types, but they only save to give something for other features to interact with, as labels. They do not confer any common properties other than what is common via these interactions. This is very different to, for example Pathfinder, where all Undead share certain properties, independent of other game features.

Comment: I see.

So assuming the [wiki](https://adnd2e.fandom.com/) is correct, it is quite odd that, for instance, Wraiths are said to be immune to Sleep, Charm, Hold, Death and Cold-based spells, whereas, say, Death Knights (another type of Undead) are not.

What should I do in such situations?

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin: I have amended the answer.

Comment: @Luke: So Death Knights are not immune to those effects. But they have 75% magic resistance. You play accordingly. Or if you don't want to, modify your Death Knights. 

Comment: @Luke: Note that there is a pattern, this immunities repeat over and over in undead descriptions, you must consider the possibility of lack of description in a monster in specific and decide as GM. Death Knight is a specific monster from Krynn available in MM too, but why be vulnerable to poison? I personally check 3e before decide.